# Abrir un dialog en Vue.js con un treeview

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web

Estoy buscando abrir un diálogo, con un evento en una vista de árbol. ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de enviar el evento?

Los problemas que tengo

1. No puedo abrir el diálogo fuera del componente de diálogo, por eso el botón está dentro del diálogo.
2. Al intentar crear cualquier evento desde la vista de árbol, se repite en todos los hijos y quiero que se despliegue cuando selecciono solo uno de los hijos.

Mis dudas específicas;

¿Cómo puedo abrir el cuadro de diálogo desde fuera del componente y cuál es la forma correcta de crear un evento para uno de los elementos secundarios del treview?

Esté es mi árbol;

```
        <v-treeview
        v-model="tree"
        :open="initiallyOpen"
        :items="options"
  activatable
  item-key="name"
  open-on-click
  class="tree"> 
  <template v-slot:prepend="{ item, open }" class="tree">
    <v-icon v-if="!item.file" color="purple">
      {{ open ? 'mdi-reorder-vertical' : 'mdi-reorder-horizontal' }}
    </v-icon>
    <v-icon v-else>
      {{ files[item.file] }}
    </v-icon>
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```

Aquí intento enviar el evento al hijo.

```
        
         options: 
         [
         {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Options',
          children: [
 
                {
                  id: 201,
                  name: 'Example',
                  file: 'Example',
```

Quiero abrir un cuadro de diálogo al hacer clic en el elemento secundario de la vista de árbol;

```
        <v-dialog
              v-model="dialog"
              persistent
              max-width="500px"
              >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
         Test Example
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="fondoAzul">
          <span class="text-h5 ">Example</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container>
            
          </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-row>
    <v-col cols="4">   </v-col>
      <v-col cols="4">
                 <v-btn
            text
            @click="dialog = false"
            class="primary right"
          >
            Save
          </v-btn>
            </v-col>
     <v-col cols="4">
          <v-btn
            text
            @click="dialog = false"
            class="primary right"
          >
            Close
          </v-btn>
           </v-col>
       </v-row>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

Agradecería mucho cualquier consejo o ayuda.

Comment: Ya, gracias ya lo corregí

Comment: Si tú mismo encontraste una solución a tu problema, puedes auto responder tu pregunta y compartir tu solución con todos. Eso puede ayudar a otros que tengan tu mismo problema.